# use current mysql connection inside class

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to write a class that will fetch table columns and eval them as variables with the data in that column. I can't seem to get `mysql_query()` to work inside the class. Does it not work because `mysql_query()` is an outside function?

```
class the_info {
    function the_info() {
        $s = mysql_query("bla bla bla");
        while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($s)) {
            $out .= $r[0];
        }
    }
}

$f = new the_info();
echo $f->out;
```

Something like that. I know I didn't declare vars.

Comment: showing code might help others to help you.

Comment: too vague, please improve question...

Comment: Too vague to get a good answer.

Comment: Please, learn about [PDO](http://ph.net/PDO) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) and prepared statements.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`mysql_query()` is an inbuild PHP function, it has nothing to do with your custom classes. May be there might be problem with query that you are using. Paste some code !!